# La imagen es nula cuando la extraigo de la BD (Android SQLite)

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

Yo guardo la foto y en principio se guarda bien; al extraer el blob no es nulo, pero cuando hago lo de `decodeByteArray` el bitmap se guarda como nulo. ¿Alguna solución?

Aquí meto el bitmap en la variable.

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Bitmap bitmap;
            try {
                bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getActivity().getContentResolver(), photoURI);
                fotoAGuardar=bitmap;//Aquí guardo el bitmap en la variable
                System.out.println("$$$$$$$ cuando lo creo"+fotoAGuardar);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED)
            photoFile.delete(); // cambio
    

}
```

Aquí guardo la foto en la BD:

```java
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
fotoAGuardar.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);
byte[] blob = baos.toByteArray(); //este es el byte con la imagen comprimida


db.execSQL("INSERT INTO Amigos (nombre, foto) VALUES ('" + nombre + "', '" + blob + "')");
```

Aquí la extraigo:

```java
String[] campos = new String[] {
    "nombre",
    "foto"
};
Cursor c = db.query("Amigos", campos, null, null, null, null, "nombre");
nombres = new ArrayList < > ();
fotos = new ArrayList < > ();

if (c.moveToFirst()) {
    do {
        nombre = c.getString(0);
        //fotos
        blob = c.getBlob(1);
        System.out.println("############### cuando saco el comprimido de la BD" + blob);

        foto = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(blob, 0, blob.length);


        //Siempre entra en este if
        if (foto == null) {
            System.out.println("########es nulo, cuando lo he descomprimido para mostrarlo");
            foto = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.contactos);
        }
        //fin
        nombres.add(nombre);
        fotos.add(foto);
    } while (c.moveToNext());
```

Comment: Y, ¿A dónde está la ruta de la imagen? ¿Dónde la guardas?

Comment: Tengo el bitmap en la variable `fotoAGuarar` . Edito el código.

Answer (score 0):

Lo he conseguido solucionar, el problema estaba (no sé por qué) a la hora de guardar el blob en la base de datos, esta vez he usado un prepared statment y ya funciona, lo dejo por aquí por si a alguien más le pasa.

```
//convertir el bitmap en un array de bites
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
fotoAGuardar.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);
byte[] blob = baos.toByteArray(); //este es el byte con la imagen comprimida

String sql = "INSERT INTO Amigos (nombre, foto) VALUES (?,?)";

SQLiteStatement statement = db.compileStatement(sql);
statement.clearBindings();
statement.bindString(1, nombre);
statement.bindBlob(2, blob);
statement.executeInsert();
```